# Failing to understand pointers?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a vector of Linked list pointers.

Each LinkedList has a head pointer which is a pointer to a Node.  That node of course is the head of the list.

The head of vector[3] is the same as the head of vector[0]. 
I change the head pointer of vector[0] to point to the same node that vector[1] points to, or the head of vector[1].

However the head pointer of vector[3] never changes.  How can I get it so that by changing the head pointer of vector[0] I can also change the head pointer of vector[3] as well? 
I have tried 2 different methods.  None have worked.

```
vector[0]->head=vector[1]->head;
*(vector[0]->head)=*(vector[1]->head);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change two values with a single assignment.

In your case there is `vector[0]->head` and `vector[1]->head`, two different pointers with two values. They will only be equal as long as you keep them so, by changing one when you change the other.

You could use an additional level of indirection:

```
Node* commonPointer = head_of_some_list;

VectorElement { ... Node **head; }

vector[0]->head = &commonPointer;
vector[3]->head = &commonPointer;

*(vector[0]->head) = head_of_another_list;
//Now *(vector[0]->head), *(vector[3]->head) and commonPointer all eventually point to head_of_another_list;
```

Though this does not smell like good design.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an easy way to solve your problem right now (will think about it :)), but I think you should understand why your code behaviour is different from what you expect.
I guess here we are talking about STL vectors, that are containers
Specifically that means that you got a *copy* of the linked list head inside each vector entry, so modifying the *copy* of the pointer in vector[i] does not affect the content of vector[j]
**My two cents:** will using a map with key = head pointer suits your need? or do you really need distinct elements to track down the same list?
Hope this helps

CiaoCiao
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

I believe your real problem here is not understanding pointers and linked lists well. Pointers can a bit challenging to understand. However, I will give a try to answer your questions.

First, note that pointers in C++ and Java act differently and that pointers come down to passing by reference and pass by pointer.

Pass by reference signifies that changes made will be kept and passing by pointer creates a copy where changes will not be permanent.

Furthermore, from what I understand you have vector[0]->head vector[3]->head pointing to the same memory address but then later changes what vector[0]->head points to. This will not change to vector[3]->head as it would still be pointing to the memory address vector[0]->head pointed to previously.

If you are trying to make them point to the same location you would have to point vector[3]->head to vector[1]->head as well.

Hope I was of help (I'm new to stack overflow).

Answer (score 0):

```
vector[0] = &HeadA; &HeadA->head points to Node A
vector[1] = &HeadB; &HeadB->head points to Node B
vector[3] = &HeadC; &HeadC->head points to Node A
```

If you change vector[0]->head to point to Node B, that doesn't change the contents of vector[3]->head because it is a completely separate variable.

Rather than setting vector[3]->head to point to Node A, you have to set vector[3] = vector[0]. That means that the 1st and 4th elements of the vector contain the same pointer to the same Head object:

```
vector[0] = &HeadA; &HeadA->head points to Node A
vector[1] = &HeadB; &HeadB->head points to Node B
vector[3] = &HeadA; &HeadA->head points to Node A
```